# Where to store user-accessible files in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.forms, filesystem-access

I have here a cross platform app, which uses `DependencyService` to get a file path for my log file. This works fine for `ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path`, but now the log file should be made accessible to the user. The idea was that the user plugs his device into the PC, copies the log file from it and then send it to me via normal email. (Currently, it is not planned to distribute the app via the store and it is not guaranteed, that the user has an email account setup on his device.)

First, I tried with `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`, but here I get `Access is denied`. If I look into the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations), this folder is not intended for my use. Other locations also doesn't seem to fit.

Is this approach feasible in UWP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**New anser:**

I found out, that `Access denied` only occurs on desktop, not mobile. Afterwards, I found [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ff62185a-5a3a-42fe-bc5a-d6bf9f60b0fa/uwpaccess-denied-while-writing-files-to-documents-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop), which describes why this does happen. It's because of the [permission handling](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/) and that I throw away my permissions. There are several possibilites how to handle this situation:

- Use a picker to ask the user
- Use [`FutureAccessList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList)

Example:

```
FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (folder != null)
{
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
}
StorageFolder newFolder;

newFolder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync("PickedFolderToken");
await newFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.txt");
```

- Use streams instead of paths (for library)
- Make a copy of the file and store it into the [application data folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh967755(v=win.10))

Example:

```
StorageFolder tempFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path, "YourApp"));
StorageFile tempFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(pathToAttachment), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(tempFile);
```

**Old answer:**

My current solution is that I offer a button in my app, which calls natively the [`FolderPicker`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers#pick-a-folder-complete-code-listing) via `DependencyService` and only on UWP. With this the user can select the location and I copy the file to this location. Works nicely, despite I wish I didn't had to do something only for one platform.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [Capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) of `documentsLibrary` to access `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`

To add go to "Package.appxmanifest" in `YourApp.UWP` > "Capability" tab and check the capability where you want to store. Example: "Picture Library" or "Removable Storage"

Comment: I still get `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`, perhaps because I'm not working with `StorageFolder` anymore? I get the error on this line `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.Path`. I have added `Removeable Storage` as capability and `<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>`, but still the same error.

Comment: The link you stated mentions *Your app can't access the Documents library in the phone's internal storage.* So can't I use this folder?